# How to copy one file into multiple subfolders at once on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, cp

I have a folder on a Linux server with 35+ subdirectories, along the lines of:

```
aa.foo.bar.baz
ab.foo.bar.baz
..
bp.foo.bar.baz
```

I have a file that I want to copy into each of those subdirectories. What's a quick way to do that without running 35+ separate *cp* commands manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in *.foo.bar.baz/; do
    cp file "$i"
done
```

Comment: what if there is a file in the current dir that matches *.foo.bar.baz?

Comment: @bryan: See updated answer. *(FWIW, `ls -d` would have listed files as well.)*

Comment: copied from the wrong terminal, added in my slash

Answer (score 2):

find . -type d | xargs -I{} cp ./myfile {}/

This is how I got the job done.

Here was the problem I wanted solved. I wanted to test all my new virtual hosts before installing the actual applications.

```
pwd 
/var/www/
find . -type d
.
./site1
./site2
./site3
find . -type d | xargs -I{} cp ./php.info {}/ 
ls ./*
./php.info

./site1:
php.info

./site2:
php.info

./site3:
php.info
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for dirname in $(ls -d *.foo.bar.baz/); do cp file $dirname; done
```

Comment: ... *no* `for in $(ls)`, please. Wildcard expansion already works for all commands.